# Iot-edge Rest API for az command "az iot edge set-modules"

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am unable to get REST API for az-cli command
"az iot edge set-modules --device-id mydevice --hub-name my-hub --content filename.json"

Comment: Is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/createorupdatemodule what you need?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/createorupdatemodule is for creating a module but I want alternative as for setting modules that are containers in some registries.....(az iot edge set-modules) asks for manifest file i.e template.json which have modules their container images and registry credentials which set-modules in a particular edge device runtime environment

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-sample-c/blob/master/deployment.template.json ...is the reference to template file and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/edge?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-iot-ext-az-iot-edge-set-modules ..is the reference to what az set-modules command do

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-modules-portal provides setting-modules through azure-portal,azure-cli ,Visual studio code but ther is no option available through Rest-API

Comment: Is this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/applyconfigurationonedgedevice which you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rest api which you are looking for: [Service - Apply Configuration On Edge Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/applyconfigurationonedgedevice)

```
POST https://fully-qualified-iothubname.azure-devices.net/devices/{id}/applyConfigurationContent?api-version=2018-06-30
```